# How to create MFTF Testing for custom module in Magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2.4, varnish, mftf, magento2.4.5, magento2marketplace

I have studied the MFTF documentation to create and test the custom module before submitting the extension to Magento Marketplace But it is difficult to understand how it works.

**Can you help me with How I create MFTF?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the structure of the mftf file

MFTF cases should be in the Test directory :

This is the directory path:

[image]

If you need more help then please let us know

This is the sample source code :

```
/app/code/Vendor/Module/Test/Mftf/ActionGroup/AdminSectionActionGroup.xml

<actionGroups xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:mftf:Test/etc/actionGroupSchema.xsd">
    <actionGroup name="AdminCatalogActionGroup">
        <amOnPage stepKey="amOnAdminCatalogPage" url="{{AdminCatalogPage.url}}"/>
        <click selector="{{AdminSection.clickOnselector}}" stepKey="clickOnTheMarketPlace"/>
        <click selector="{{AdminSection.clickOnConfig}}" stepKey="clickOnConfig"/>
        <click selector="{{AdminSection.clickOnCatalog}}" stepKey="clickOnCatalog"/>
        <scrollTo selector="//a[@id='module-head']" stepKey="scrollToAnchor"/>
        <selectOption stepKey="productTypeId"
                      parameterArray= "['Configurable Product','Grouped Product']"
                      selector="{{AdminCatalogSection.productType}}"/>
        <click selector="{{AdminSection.ClickOnAttribute}}" stepKey="ClickOnAttribute"/>
        <selectOption stepKey="attributeType"
                      parameterArray= "['Short Description','Special Price']"
                      selector="{{AdminSection.attributeType}}"/>
        <scrollToTopOfPage stepKey="onTopOfPage"/>
        <click selector="{{AdminSection.clickOnCatalog}}" stepKey="clickOnCatalogAgain"/>
        <click selector="{{AdminSection.clickOnTheSave}}" stepKey="SaveConfiguration"/>
    </actionGroup>
</actionGroups>
```

Other File is :

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Test/Mftf/Data/AdminAddProductData.xml

<entities xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:mftf:DataGenerator/etc/dataProfileSchema.xsd">
    <entity name="AdminAddSecondProductData" type="SecondProductsData">
        <data key="productName">demoproduct</data>
        <data key="Sku">demoproduct123</data>
        <data key="Price">520</data>
        <data key="Qty">313</data>
    </entity>
</entities>
```

The File under Page is :

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Test/Mftf/Page/AdminSectionPage.xml


<pages xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:mftf:Page/etc/PageObject.xsd">
    <page name="AdminCatalogPage" url="dashboard/" area="admin" module="Vendor_Module">
    </page>
</pages>
```

Under the Section File :

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Test/Mftf/Section/AdminSection.xml


<sections xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:mftf:Page/etc/SectionObject.xsd">
    <section name="AdminCatalogSection">
        <element name="clickOnTheanything" type="button" selector="#menu" timeout="1000"/>
        <element name="clickOnConfig" type="button" selector="//li[@data-ui-id='menu-vendor-module-configuration']//a//span" timeout="1000"/>
        <element name="clickOnCatalog" type="button" selector="//a[@id='vendor_module-head']" timeout="1000"/>
    </section>
</sections>
```

Under the Test Section :

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Test/Mftf/Test/AdminSectionTest.xml


<tests xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:mftf:Test/etc/testSchema.xsd">
    <test name="AdminCatalogTest">
        <annotations>
            <title value="Demo Test"/>
            <stories value="Showing Configuration Added successfully "/>
            <description value="Verify Demo Test"/>
        </annotations>
        <before>
            <actionGroup ref="AdminLogin" stepKey="login"/>
        </before>
        <after>
            <actionGroup ref="AdminCatalogActionGroup" stepKey="AdminCatalogConfiguration">
            </actionGroup>
        </after>
    </test>
</tests>
```

Comment: can you please provide some demo source code for the related MFTF test?

Comment: Please check my updated answer now

Comment: If this might help you please mark this an answer

Comment: thanks for help

Comment: Please mark this an answer, if this helps you